# On rotating magnetic charges

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment, magnetic-monopoles

Consider a sphere with magnetic charge $P$ and electric charge $Q$. We know that when the sphere is subjected to rotation about the $z$-axis, there is a magnetic dipole moment generated from the rotating electric charge. Is it then correct to say that equivalently, there should be an electric dipole moment generated from the rotating magnetic charge?

Comment: How do you define a magnetic charge?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Yeah, this is my question too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, if there are magnetic charges, the math predicts what you say. But physics isn't math.

In physics, the way to to test a hypothesis is to perform an experiment. So, get a magnetically charged sphere and rotate it. Oops, no such thing has ever been seen to exist.